# handle syntax error, unexpected T_IF in PHP

Tags: php, xml

I need to create a search of string in an XML file on all nodes.

---catalog.xml---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<Catalog>
<Category>
<Name>Biscuit</Name>
<Location>
   <Id>Butter</Id>
   <Description>The butter biscuit cost $10 per pack</Description>
  </Location>
  <Location>
   <Id>Chocolate</Id>
   <Description>The chocolate biscuit cost $20 per pack</Description>
  </Location>
 </Category>
 <Category>
  <Name>Cake</Name>
  <Location>
   <Id>Cup</Id>
   <Description>This is a cup cake</Description>
  </Location>
  <Location>
   <Id>Slice</Id>
   <Description>This is a slice cake</Description>
  </Location>
 </Category>
</Catalog>
```

---search.php---

```
<?php
$catalog = simplexml_load_file("catalog.xml");
$category = $catalog->Category;
$location = $category->Location;

foreach($location->Description as $desc)
{
 $string = string($desc);
 $find = 'chocolate';

 $result = strpos($string, $find)

 if ($result !== false)
 {
  echo $result;
 }
 else
 {
  echo "No Result";
 }
}
?>
```

---

The error I received is:

`Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_IF on line 14`

Since there is "chocolate" at node  and  Node, I need to display both node result.

----New Amended Code / 20 Nov 2012---

```
<?php

$catalog = simplexml_load_file("catalog.xml");

$find = "chocolate";

$lcFind = strtolower($find);
$ll = implode('', range('a', 'z'));
$ul = strtoupper($ll);
$xpath_result = $catalog->xpath("//*[contains(translate(text(), '$ul','$ll'),'$lcFind')]");

if ($xpath_result) {
foreach ($xpath_result as $res)  {

$category = $catalog->Category;
$name = $category->Name;
$loc = $category->Location;
$id = $loc->Id;

echo "Category: ", $name, "<br />";
echo "ID: ", $id, "<br />";
echo "Description :", $res, "<br />";
}
}
else {
echo "No matching descriptions found for word '<i>$find</i>'<br />";
}
?>
```

Result (Wrong):

Category: Biscuit
ID: Butter     //This should be "Chocolate"
Description :Chocolate //This should be the description for "Chocolate"
Category: Biscuit
ID: Butter
Description :The chocolate biscuit cost $20 per pack

Comment: What does the message `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_IF on line 14` tell you? And what is on line 14? And what is right before that, as opposed to what should be there?

Answer (score 1):

It should be...

```
$result = strpos($string, $find);
```

You should finish your statements with semicolons in PHP. And it'd probably be quite a nice idea using IDE (or even a text editor) with PHP syntax check.

... Yet there's only the beginning of the problem (and I'm not talking about non-existing `string` function here). See, with this code you're trying to search for some term only in descriptions of the *first* location of the first *category*. If that's actually the task, ok, but somehow I feel your original intent is better expressed with this:

```
$found = false;
foreach ($catalog->Category as $category) {
  foreach($category->Location as $location) {
    $description = "{$location->Description}";
    $result = strpos($description, $find);
    if ($result !== FALSE) {
      echo "Word '<i>$find</i>' found in <b>$description</b> at position " . ($result + 1) . '.<br />';
      $found = true;
    }
  }
}
if (! $found) {
  echo "No matching descriptions found for word '<i>$find</i>'<br />";
}
```

And even this can be optimized with XPath - especially if you actually don't need to echo the position:

```
$xpath_result = $catalog->xpath("//Description[contains(text(),'$find')]");
if ($xpath_result) {
  foreach ($xpath_result as $res)  {
    echo "Word '<i>$find</i>' found in <b>$res</b><br />";
  }
}
else {
  echo "No matching descriptions found for word '<i>$find</i>'<br />";
}
```

... or, for case-insensitive search:

```
$lcFind = strtolower($find);
$ll = implode('', range('a', 'z'));
$ul = strtoupper($ll);
$xpath_result = $catalog->xpath("//*[contains(translate(text(), '$ul', '$ll'),'$lcFind')]");
... // the rest of code is the same
```

Comment: my intention is to search the whole XML file, rather that restricted to some certain node.

Comment: @user1787756 Change `//Description` to `//*` in `xpath` example then (to catch all the nodes, not only of special type).

Comment: The first code works but that is more statics.  I need to search whole XML file within all nodes.

Comment: Error;  Warning: SimpleXMLElement::xpath() [simplexmlelement.xpath]: Missing closing curly brace in /home/a3440614/public_html/search.php on line 5


Warning: SimpleXMLElement::xpath() [simplexmlelement.xpath]: xmlXPathEval: evaluation failed in /home/a3440614/public_html/search.php on line 5

No matching descriptions found for word ''

Comment: hmmm....changed //* in xpath but it returns:  Word 'chocolate' found in The chocolate biscuit cost $20 per pack.  The <Id> node did not appear.  Is there anything missing?

Comment: Of course. You search for `'chocolate'`, but this node contains `'Chocolate'` instead. Do you need to make this search case-insensitive?

Comment: @user1787756 Added this option to the answer.

Comment: I insert a new code above to show the node which the category is in but the output is wrong.  How can I correct it?  Meaning if the $res is found, the parent node and child node should display.

Comment: If term is found in the category name, which of child nodes the code should show?

Comment: <Category>
<Name>Biscuit</Name>
<Location>
   <Id>Chocolate</Id>
   <Description>The chocolate biscuit cost $20 per pack</Description>
  </Location>
 </Category>

Comment: I've searched for `Biscuit` here. What should the code show? Which of Location nodes?

Comment: Show the output expected when 'biscuit' is searched for, please. It can be found in both location subnodes, right?

Comment: for this instant, the word chocolate is searched and appear in both the sub node Location->Id and Description so it should display the parent node to Category->Name, Location->Id, Location->Description

Comment: if you searched by word Biscuit, it should appear 2 different node at Category->Name since there are 2 of them, then display both child node to Location->Description

Comment: The concept is like a search, but in terms of result, it should display all result of $find(string) with the whole block of nodes.